# Exchange Hybrid configuration is not working as expected

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, microsoft-office-365

I have an on premises exchange 2013 setup, and I am trying to have a hybrid setup between office 365 and this on premises. But when I try to create a migration endpoint, it says that the connection to server could not be completed.

[image]
[image]

Technet doc says I need to enable MRS Proxy Service, but I can't see such an option.

[image]

Even if I try to enable hybrid, I am recieving the following errors:

[image]

Can someone please help me where I am going wrong @ the earliest. Thanks in advance.

Update:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Notice that in addition to the cert validation issue, it looks like DNS for Autodiscover might be off.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: Do you mean that we need to have a specific server in the name autodiscover.domain.com? and have a dns for this.?

Comment: Look at your own images: "Attempting to locate SRV record _autodiscover._tcp.<domain>.com in DNS". You have to fix *all* of these problems for Autodiscover, ActiveSync, and hybrid migrations to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have ActiveSync and possibly AutoDiscover working for the on-premise organization in order to do a hybrid coexistence migration. Use the [Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/) to check that Exchange ActiveSync and AutoDiscover are working. A common problem here is not having the correct certificates installed correctly.

Comment: Thanks! We've tried using a self signed cert, but the errors posted above. Since this is a POC, we don't want to pay for certificate. Can you please let me know if there's any other alternative to this issue.?

Comment: As far as I have been able to tell, there is no way to successfully hybrid without purchasing a cert, and not just any cert, I think you have to get a UC cert. I've tried it with a wildcard cert and had trouble.

Comment: Thanks. But why we are not able to setup migration endpoint? Any idea

Comment: You have to have a cert signed by a recognized CA. Look at the actual error messages in the images you added to your answer.